# Construction of time flow with three fixed points

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to construct a time flow $f:\mathbb{R}\times [-1,1]\to [-1,1]$ (ideally smooth) such that $-1,0,1$ are fixed points (that is $f(t,x)=x$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x=-1,0,1$) of which $-1$ and $1$ are stable und $0$ is unstable. I don't know if the terminology is correct but I want a flow that approaches $1$ when started in some $x>0$ and approaches $-1$ when started in $x<0$. In formulas:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} f(x,t)=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } x>0\\
0&\text{if }x=0\\-1&\text{if }x<0\end{cases} $$

and 
$$\lim_{t\to-\infty} f(x,t)=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } x=1\\
0&\text{if }-1<x<1\\-1&\text{if }x=-1\end{cases} $$

I tried some things and it is pretty obvious how the function should look like but I didn't succeed in constructing it explicitly. I thought about writing down some ODE with those fixedpoints (I think $y_x'=y_x-y_x^3$, $y_x(0)=x$ should do it), solving it and then defining $f(t,x)=y_x(t)$. But no success so far.

**Sorry for the bad tags and (probably) wrong terminology.**

Comment: How about $\dot{x} = sin(\pi x)$?

Comment: Ah, sorry, this is similar to $\dot{x} = x - x^3$